# How do I extract only part of a matched string with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
'https://twitter.com/pixelhenk/status/891303699204714496'.match(/\/status\/(\d+)/g)
```

gives me

```
[ "/status/891303699204714496" ]
```

How do I get just the number? I thought putting it in parentheses did this, but apparently not.

Comment: Use `exec()` instead.

Comment: The number is in the first capturing group.

Comment: @ctwheels: We can mark multiple ones. :-)

Comment: Does it HAVE to be regex? `const num = 'https://twitter.com/pixelhenk/status/891303699204714496'.split("/").pop();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a capture group does this. You don't see it in your array because you've used `String#match` and the `g` flag. Either remove the `g` flag (and take the second entry from the array, which is the first capture group):

```js
console.log('https://twitter.com/pixelhenk/status/891303699204714496'.match(/\/status\/(\d+)/)[1]);
```

...or use `RegExp#exec` instead of `String#match`.

```js
console.log(/\/status\/(\d+)/g.exec('https://twitter.com/pixelhenk/status/891303699204714496')[1]);
```